# Revoke an entire celery canvas workflow

Tags: python, concurrency, celery, amqp

I have trouble finding a way to do the following:

I have a "complex" celery workflow:

```
r = chain(
        one.si(), 
        chord(
            header=group(
                two.si(), 
                three.si()
            ), 
            body=four.si()
        )
    ).delay()
```

r.revoke(terminate=True) only stop the first task ("one") and ignore the others.

I need to revoke all tasks while any of them is running.

For example:

While task "two" is running I need to stop the workflow and revoke the parallel tasks "two" an "three" and the callback of the chord (task "four").

Is there any way to do this in celery?